# I'm trying to assign a variable to check-boxes and adding that variable to an output variable when it's checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm very new to Javascript and would appreciate ANY help! I'm also using a jQuery library if that changes anything.

What I need is that if the first `checkbox` was ticked the output should be 100kcal, while if both were ticked then it should add up to 300kcal. My problem is that when I untick it adds the variables AGAIN.

HTML:

```
<input type=checkbox onchange="myFunction(100)" value="scrambledEggs">Scrambled Eggs</input>
<input type=checkbox onchange="myFunction(200)" value="bacon">Bacon</input>
<p id="output">0kcal</p>
```

JS:

```
var result = 0;    
function myFunction(x) {    
    if (this.checked) {    
        result -= x;   
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result + "kcal";    
    } 
    else {
        result += x;
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result + "kcal";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly if you're using jQuery, you should use it to attach the event handlers instead of `onchange` attributes. Secondly, the `input` tag is self closing - your current HTML is invalid. Finally, you can use a `data` attribute to store the kcal value for the option:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="food-option" data-kcals="100" value="scrambledEggs" />Scrambled Eggs</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="food-option" data-kcals="200" value="bacon" />Bacon</label>
<p id="output"><span>0</span>kcal</p>
```

Then you can use jQuery to attach the event and total up all the checked values and display them:

```
$('.food-option').change(function() {
    var totalKcals = 0;
    $('.food-option:checked').each(function() {
       totalKcals += parseInt($(this).data('kcals'), 10); 
    });
    $('#output span').text(totalKcals);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sd5jm/4/)

Comment: thanks SO MUCH! xD I'm working on my first webpage and this is going to help me out so much! :D

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can use this code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="scrambledEggs" data-kcal="100">scrambledEggs</input>
<input type="checkbox" value="bacon" data-kcal="200">bacon</input>
<p id="output"> 0 kcal</p>
```

it have `data-kcal` tag which is container for your kcal value.

**JS**

```
var result = 0;

$('input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function() {
    if($(this).attr('checked'))
    {
        result += parseInt($(this).attr("data-kcal"));
    }else{
        result -= ($(this).attr("data-kcal"));
    }
    $("#output").text(result + " kcal");
});
```

Also you can check how it works on [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tujrG/).

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML should be like below

```
<input type='checkbox' value="100">Scrambled Eggs  </input>
<input type='checkbox' value="200"> Bacon </input>
<p id="output">0kcal </p>
```

Then you better use JQuery, less code written, more readability. The code below will achieve your needs.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function (e) { //This will trigger every check/uncheck event for any input of type CheckBox.
    var res = 0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() { //Loop through every checked checkbox.
       res += parseInt($(this).val());  //Sum it's value.
    });
    $('#output').text(res); //Add the final result to your span.
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hqHdr/1/)**

Comment: `value` may not always be an appropriate choice though, for example when you need to submit the form to be processed on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the element that is clicked into the function...

**HTML**

```
<input type=checkbox onchange="myFunction(this, 200)" value="bacon">Bacon</input>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function myFunction(element, value) {
    console.log(element.checked);
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErNDC/1/) for a demo.

---

Better way of doing it is like this...

**HTML**

```
<div id="checkboxes">
    <input type=checkbox value="bacon">Bacon</input>
    <input type=checkbox value="Other">Other</input>
</div>
<p id="output">0kcal</p>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");

checkboxes.onchange = function (e) {
    alert("Target: " +  e.target.value + " Checked: " + e.target.checked);
};
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErNDC/2/) for a demo.